# redirect_to another controller from link_to with remote=>true in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a rails project, I have 2 controllers, I use `link_to` with `remote => true` for creating a new `assignmenttable`. I have below code:

`assignmettables_controller.rb`

```
class AssignmenttablesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_assignmenttable, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @assignmenttable = Assignmenttable.new
  end

  def create
    @assignmenttable = Assignmenttable.new
    @assignmenttable.current_user_id = params[:current_user_id]
    @assignmenttable.task_id = params[:task_id]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @assignmenttable.save
        format.html { redirect_to new_reporter_path, notice: 'Assignmenttable was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @assignmenttable }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @assignmenttable.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`views/assignmettables/_form.html.erb`

```
<%= link_to "submit", assignmenttables_path(:current_user_id => user.id, :task_id => params[:task_id]), :remote => true,  :method => "post" %>
```

Now, when I click on `submit`, this 2 parameters pass to `create` action in controller and new `assignmenttable` is create in database, I want when `assignmenttable` is saved, page is `redirect_to` another controller(`new_reporter_path`), but the page is stay in `assignmettable/new` and don't occur any action. How can I do this?(redirect page to `new_reporter_path` after saving `assignmenttable` in database and then show a message).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#link-to). When you use link_to remote: true you replace page request with ajax request. So your redirect stays inside of this ajax request and not occurs in your browser. So you have two possible solutions:

1. Remove remote: true, because you need to redirect user after action, so there is no use to ajaxify this request.
2. Redirect on client on success of ajax request (see first link in my answer).

But second solution is stupid because of only reason for you to use ajax in that request is to avoid page reload.

Comment: How can i redirect_to a different Controller as format js??